# To copy Cell values from a range and paste it in a single row of another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Wanted to accomplish below mentioned task,
Having 2 Sheets(Sheet1 and Sheet 2)
On clicking the Checkbox on Sheet 1:J1, data present in the table form on the Sheet 1 should get pasted in the single row of Sheet2
For e.g Product 1 data (P1) to the Product 1 Column, Product 2 data (P2) to the Product 2 Column  and so on...
For every new submit, new data to be recorded on the next row of Sheet2.
SS link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tmnDOMyupjeO8d65qHQsxb5KrrKeq7pMYIE8h2VmEJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a checkbox of "H1" of "Sheet1" is checked, you want to copy the values from the cells "A3:G6" to the columns "B" to "AC" in one row of "Sheet2".
- And, you want to copy "B1" and "B10" of "Sheet1" to the columns "A" and "AD" of "Sheet2".
- In your Spreadsheet, there are no merged cells.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.getA1Notation() != "H1" || !range.isChecked()) return;
  const srcRange = sheet.getRange("A3:G6");
  const [[b1], , , , , , , , , [b10]] = sheet.getRange("B1:B10").getValues();
  const values = [b1, ...srcRange.getValues().flat(), b10];
  const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  dstSheet.appendRow(values);
  range.uncheck();
  // srcRange.clearContent();
}
```

- This script is automatically run with the simple trigger of OnEdit trigger. So, when you use this script, please check the checkbox of "H1" of "Sheet1". By this, the script is run. When you directly run the script, an error like `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to clear the source range after the values were copied, please use `srcRange.clearContent();`.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So, when you changed your Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Dear, Thanks for the solution. Could you please recheck, that merged cells were done mistakenly and now I am also having Customer name and Total amount that needs to be added on the Sheet2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Could you please recheck, that merged cells were done mistakenly and now I am also having Customer name and Total amount that needs to be added on the Sheet2.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because if my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: Your answer was perfect to copy paste the data in the array i.e. A3:I6(now A3:G16), but i am having Customer name in B1 and Total amount in B10 that too need to be pasted in Sheet 2

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. From `Your answer was perfect to copy paste the data in the array i.e. A3:I6`, I confirmed that my answer resolved your question. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `but i am having Customer name in B1 and Total amount in B10 that too need to be pasted in Sheet 2`, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot find it. In your Spreadsheet, the column "B" of "Sheet2" is "Category 1". So, I cannot understand what you want to do. When I saw your question again, I cannot find out it. This is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: My 70% problem solved by your script, tonnes of thanks for that. Kindly give a last try if possible, I'll try to explain you in detail. My purpose got solved of Copying data(A3:I6) from Sheet1 to Sheet 2 however there are Values in Cell B1 and B10 of Sheet1 which also need to be pasted in Sheet2.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. About `My purpose got solved of Copying data(A3:I6) from Sheet1 to Sheet 2 however there are Values in Cell B1 and B10 of Sheet1 which also need to be pasted in Sheet2.`, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, no values of "B1" and "B10" are existing. So, I couldn't notice your additional request. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. So, can I ask you where do you want to put the values of "B1" and "B10" of "Sheet1" to?

Comment: B1 (Customer Name) and B10 (Total Amount) from Sheet1 needs to be pasted in the Column A (Customer Name) and Column AD (Total Amount) of Sheet2.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh I would like to confirm about your reply. Now, I saw your provided Spreadsheet again, I was surprised that your Spreadsheet had been changed. In your current situation, you had changed your initial specification? My answer is your initial question. But, now, are you saying the problem of your changed specification to my answer for your initial question? If my understanding is correct, I have to modify my answer. So, I would like to confirm it. I apologize that I couldn't notice that your question had been changed. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Dear, i owe your efforts. I agree that i added customer field as i missed it initially. Let me elaborate the requirement now. I have following data in Sheet1 ::: B1- Customer Name, B10-Total Amount and A3:G6 containing product informations. Need to paste this entire data in Sheet 2 in their respective columns in a single row.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your question had been changed. So, in this case, it is also required to change my answer. So, can you give me some time to do it? And, in your 1st question, the columns "C" to "D" are merged. But in your new question, there are no merged cells. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes you understood it correct, please take your time and help me in getting the required data collected and pasted in a single row in Sheet 2 everytime the checkbox is checked to True.

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. About your changed specification, I changed my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. By the way, I think that your new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72515877 is the same with this question. So, I would like to recommend to delete https://stackoverflow.com/q/72515877